# Can't clearInterval on animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval, clearinterval

I have some problem with this code, in this case i set div as a button, when I click the button everything is working as expected but when I want to stop animation with clearInterval it doesn’t work, just keeps looping... What I am doing wrong?

```
var timeout; 
var d1=$(".drum1");

function dani1(){
d1.animate({height:'150px', width:'150px', opacity:'0.4'},"slow");
d1.animate({height:'100px', width:'100px',opacity:'0.8'},"fast");
}

d1.click(function(){
if (!timeout){
    timeout = setInterval(dani1, 200);
} else {
     clearInterval(timeout);
     timeout = null;
   }
});

<div class="drum1" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery animation does not need `setInterval` - it performs animation by itself. You can stop this animation by `d1.stop(true,true)`, read manual - http://api.jquery.com/stop/ Moreover, with your short `setInterval` period it creates a large queue of animations, followed one by another, that is why it does not want to 'stop' - it  tries to complete all animations in queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `setInterval` at all..

```js
var d1 = $(".drum1").data('end', true);

function dani1() {
  if (d1.data('end'))
    return d1.stop(true, true);
  
  d1.animate({
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px',
    opacity: '0.4'
  }, "slow")
    .animate({
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    opacity: '0.8'
  }, "fast", dani1);
}

d1.click(function() {
 if (!d1.data('end'))
    d1.data('end', true);
 else {
    d1.data('end', false);
    dani1();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drum1" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks it works like charm! btw i cut out dani1 after the "fast" in the animation part, and it still working, is that necessary?

Comment: `, "fast", dani1);` tells to loop the cycle of animation. When this animation with "fast" ends it calls the function `dani1()` again.

Comment: ok noted, just want to say thank you all for such speedy answer

Comment: may i ask 1 more question? when 1st load of the web, the button won't do anything on 1st click, it only show animation while on 2nd click, how to make it respond on 1st click?

Comment: @withinboy You can make `var d1 = $(".drum1").data('end', true);` originally data does not exist, so the first request to it returns `undefined` inverse of which (`!undefined`) is equal to `true`. Or add attribute `data-end=true` to the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your usage of `setInterval()`, it will queue a lot of animations every 200ms so even after clearing the interval there are a lot of animations present in the animation queue.

One easy solution is to clear the animation queue also

```js
var timeout;
var d1 = $(".drum1");

function dani1() {
  d1.animate({
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px',
    opacity: '0.4'
  }, "slow");
  d1.animate({
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    opacity: '0.8'
  }, "fast");
}

d1.click(function() {
  if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setInterval(dani1, 200);
  } else {
    d1.stop(true, true)
    clearInterval(timeout);
    timeout = null;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drum1" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

---

Without interval

```js
var play;
var d1 = $(".drum1");

function dani1() {
  d1.animate({
    height: '150px',
    width: '150px',
    opacity: '0.4'
  }, "slow");
  d1.animate({
    height: '100px',
    width: '100px',
    opacity: '0.8'
  }, "fast");
  return d1.promise();
}

d1.click(function() {
  if (play) {
    play = false;
    d1.stop(true, true)
  } else {
    play = true;
    anim();
  }

  function anim() {
    dani1().done(function() {
      if (play === true) {
        anim();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="drum1" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```